# Cant figure out why my div output isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic hangman program. Click on the letter, it then tells you if its right or wrong by coloring the letter red or green. If its green, it replaces a dash in the hidden word with the letter. That part of my code works. The part that doesn't work is that I have an output section to a div that is supposed to tell you if you got the guess correct or not, and upon 6 failed guesses, you lose and it resets. It's currently not doing any of that. It's not even displaying anything in the div at all.

TY ahead of time. If you have questions about something I didn't explain well enough, ill be back in about 1 hour to answer them. Thanks!

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/25b3fr4u/

HTML -

```
<body>


<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="button" id="but" value="Start"/>
<div id="hangman-jquery">
    <div id="word"></div>
    <div id="alpha"></div>
</div>
</form>

<div id="win">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="hangman.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS -

```
function hangman(word) {
    var trys = 0;
    var guess = 0;
    var alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $.each(alpha.split(''), function(i, val) {
        $('#alpha').append($('<span class="guess">' + val + '</span>'));
    });
    $.each(word.split(''), function(i, val) {
        $('#word').append($('<span class="letter" letter="' + val + '">-</span>'));
    });
    $('.guess').click(function() {
        var count = $('#word [letter=' + $(this).text() + ']').each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('letter'));
        }).length;
        $(this).removeClass('guess').css('color', (count > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')).unbind('click');

        if (guess > 0) {
        $('#win').text("Correct Guess");
        } else if (guess < 0) {
        $(this).html(++trys);
        $('#win').text("You have tried to guess the word and failed " + trys + " times");
        }
        if (trys == 6) {
        alert("You have guessed six times, you lose");
        trys = 0;
        $("#win").text("");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but').click(function() {
        var options = new Array("DOG", "CAT", "BAT", "HORSE", "TIGER", "LION", "BEAR", "LIGER", "DOOM", "SPIDER", "TREES", "LAPTOP");
        var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
        hangman(options[random]);
    });
});
```

Comment: While full code is better, could you create a shorter version highlighting your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Code fixed :http://jsfiddle.net/25b3fr4u/1/. The trys where not incremeted properly and you have to check the count instead of guess in your condition. guess was set to 0 and never use.

```
var count = $('#word [letter=' + $(this).text() + ']').each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('letter'));
    }).length;
    $(this).removeClass('guess').css('color', (count > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')).unbind('click');

    if (count > 0) {
    $('#win').text("Correct Guess");
    } else if (!count > 0) {
    trys++;
    $('#win').text("You have tried to guess the word and failed " + trys + " times");
    }
    if (trys == 6) {
    alert("You have guessed six times, you lose");
    trys = 0;
    $("#win").text("");
    }
```

I'm sure you can handle the rest. Have fun.

Comment: not much of an answer just saying `code fixed` and expecting people to be code diff tools to figure out changes, or why they fixed anything

Comment: My bad. I added some comments. I'm sorry for this and i will post complete answer in the futur. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I appreciate the help regardless. I need to learn some from what he posted. Wasn't a waste, thank you!